# How to avoid using too many if statements in VBA?

Tags: vba, if-statement

I want to exclude blank rows from all my ComboBoxes in a form, but can't find a practical way of doing so. I came up with this example:

```
Dim Foo as Worksheet: Foo = Sheets("Foo")

With UserForm
    'The ComboBoxes have unique names, this code is just an example
    For i = 0 To Foo.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Foo.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> "" Then
            .ComboBoxFoo.AddItem (Foo.Cells(i + 1, 1))
        End If
        If Foo.Cells(i + 1, 2) <> "" Then
            .ComboBoxBar.AddItem (Foo.Cells(i + 1, 2))
        End If
        If Foo.Cells(i + 1, 3) <> "" Then
            .ComboBoxBaz.AddItem (Foo.Cells(i + 1, 3))
        End If

        '[etc. etc.]

    Next

End With
```

I have plenty of ComboBoxes in my form, and all above statements look the same. There must be a more efficient way?

Solved the **blank** and **unique** issue with

```
Dim Foo As Worksheet: Foo = Sheet("Foo")
Dim Unique As Boolean

With UserForm
    'The ComboBoxes have unique names, this code is just an example
    For i = 0 To Foo.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(Foo.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
            Unique = True
            For j = 0 To .ComboBoxFoo.ListCount - 1
                If .ComboBoxFoo.List(j) = Foo.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
                    Unique = False
                Else: Unique = True
                End If
            Next j
            If Unique Then .ComboBoxFoo.AddItem (Foo.Cells(i + 1, 1))
        End If


        '[etc. etc.]

    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Why not just remove blanks before hand, or filter for non-blanks and use `UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to loop through

Comment: @MacroMan is there a risk this solution will mess with the row and column referenses? eg. column 2 row 5 is used to pull data from column 4 row 5 etc. Otherwise its a god suggestion

Comment: @Krusing `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` don't mess with range, the range will only contain visible cells, it's like an union of range. If you select `Range("A1:A7")` and only rows A2 A3 A5 have value, it will return A2 A3 A5. If you want to use the i indice to find the row, replace `for i = 0 to .Count` with `for each cell in range` and use `cell.row` instead of `i` to have the row

Answer (score 4):

You can try the code below:

```
Dim Foo As Worksheet: Foo = Sheets("Foo")

With UserForm
    For i = 0 To Foo.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To 10
            If Foo.Cells(i + 1, j) <> "" Then
                Call .Controls("ComboBox" & j).AddItem(Foo.Cells(i + 1, j))
            End If
        Next j
    Next

End With
```

It uses second `For ... Next` loop nested inside the first one. Combo boxes are referred by name, using `.Controls` collection of UserForm.

Comment: I would love this solution if I did not have unique names for the comboboxes. Sorry for not mensioning this in my question. Also, is there a way to count controls by type?

Answer (score 1):

How About:

```
Sub SO()
    For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:C")).Cells
        If Not cell.Value = "" Then AssignToCB cell.Column, cell.Value
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AssignToCB(cbNumber As Integer, value As String)
    Select Case cbNumber
        Case 1: ComboBoxFoo.AddItem value
        Case 2: ComboBoxBar.AddItem value
        Case 3: ComboBoxBaz.AddItem value
    End Select
End Sub
```